# [NETTY]: map urlpath to method

Tags: java, url, mapping, netty

I am using netty and trying implement a simple HTTP server for some API.  While I have incoming requests I can get the path of url = /foo/bar/other/.  How can I map the path to the following?

```
class = foo 
method = bar 
param = other
```

Can I use Regex? Or is there a better solution?

---

yeah i know how to split url path and get query string params. I get all params from http headers, ip etc... it's not problem. Question is, how map these path to classes and methods. So that I could bring required class and method.

simple implement some (just pseudo code):

```
public class Mapper {
    private String htttpMethod;
    private String controllerName;
    private String methodName;
}

ArrayList<Mapper> m = new ArrayList<Mapper>();
m.add(new Mapper("GET","HomeController","index"));
```

So /Home/index/1/ must rise HomeController.index(1);

for each pattern that I want to find, I need a new regular expression? Check for all, will too many if / else blocks...

Any solution about that?

But thanks for not too lazy, for the sake of this question read the docks. And sry for my English

Answer (score 0):

I find looking at the [Netty Snoop example](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/snoop/HttpSnoopServerHandler.java) helps.

```
public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) throws Exception {
    HttpRequest request = this.request = (HttpRequest) e.getMessage();

    // Get your path
    String uri = request.getUri();
    String[] segments = uri.split("/");
    String className = segments[0];
    String methodName = segments[1];

    // Get your query string parameters
    QueryStringDecoder queryStringDecoder = new QueryStringDecoder(request.getUri());

}
```

Hope this helps.